# 3llomi / iRecordView not working in release mode iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avaudiorecorder

I'm developing a messenger app in which I'm using https://github.com/3llomi/iRecordView library to record voice messages. Everything works fine in debug mode. But when I release the app to App Store and later use the app after downloading from App Store it does not work.

Expected behaviour is that on pressing the record button it makes sound and starts recording as shown in the demo https://github.com/3llomi/iRecordView

But in release mode (App downloaded from App Store) when I press the button nothing happens. There are no crash reports on App Store Connect. Could someone please help me on how could I get device logs or what the problem could be?

From what I could guess is that `RecordViewDelegate` methods are not being called

```
self.recordView.delegate = self
```

is not working I guess. Any suggestions how this could be resolved?

Comment: This is third party code (a cocoa pod). Wouldn't this be a question for the author of that code? You didn't show enough of _your_ code for us to be able to help you.

Comment: Hello Matt, I've updated on Github as well, but posted here in case some has faced this earlier...

Comment: The GitHub code includes an Example. https://github.com/3llomi/iRecordView/tree/master/Example Are you saying that _that_ doesn't work in a release build?

Comment: Yes. It's not working in release build. I used the same example in my project.

Comment: Nice! But then I would strongly suggest that this doesn't belong on Stack Overflow. There's nothing we can contribute to an issue with third party code. This is between you and the author of the code.

Comment: Totally, just in case someone has used this library earlier could be able to help me, I guess there are more chances here to get the solution :)

Comment: @Arjun Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Not yet @Gautam. Please let me know if you find any.